# material ui pagination component text color to be grey

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui, react-with-styles

I am using Material UI's pagination component and would like the text portion of the component to be grey. The color i want is white for action button and grey for text portion. Is there any way I can do this in which i decide the color of the text portion? Essentially would like the text to be grey like the left action arrow in photo.

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import TablePagination from '@material-ui/core/TablePagination';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withTheme, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexShrink: 0,
     color: theme.palette.common.white,
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 2.5,
  },
});

const PortfolioPagination = ({
  numOfItems, rowsPerPage, page, handleChangePage, classes
}) => {
  return (
    <div >
      <TablePagination
        component="div"
        className={classes.root}
        count={numOfItems}
        page={page}
        onChangePage={handleChangePage}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[]}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage} />
    </div>

  );
};

PortfolioPagination.defaultProps = {

};

PortfolioPagination.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  numOfItems: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  rowsPerPage: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  page: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  handleChangePage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default withTheme()(withStyles(styles)(PortfolioPagination));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently came across the same issue and solved it by using the style customization points of the component. Here is an example:

```js
import { TablePagination } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  color: {
    color: "green"
  },
  leftIconButton: {
    color: "blue !important"
  },
  rightIconButton: {
    color: "red !important"
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TablePagination
        classes={{
          root: classes.color
        }}
        backIconButtonProps={{ className: classes.leftIconButton }}
        nextIconButtonProps={{ className: classes.rightIconButton }}
        rowsPerPageOptions={5}
        component="div"
        count={10}
        rowsPerPage={5}
        page={1}
        onChangePage={() => {}}
        onChangeRowsPerPage={() => {}}
      />{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Live Demo

[image: Edit late-field-s59ox]